# TableAdapter fields not in right order

Tags: c#, winforms, tableadapter

I have two TableAdapters in a project. Both are used to create a csv file that is sent to an application to create accounts. We recently moved a server so the connection string of one of the TableAdapters had to be changed. Now the fields in that one will not show up in the right order on the Dataset Designer page.

Thus it is sending the csv file to the other application with the fields in the wrong order. Is there any way to manually force those fields to show up in the correct order? The underlying SQL query does select them in the right order but they will not show up in the right order after hitting finish.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: I can give an example. I am selecting acct, id, l_name, middle, f_name from the database. But in the table adapter it reorders it as acct, l_name, f_name, middle, id. So therefore the application doesn't know what to do since the csv is out of order.

Comment: Still need the code to be able to help you. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There is no code needed to answer if there is a way to manually reorder the fields. It is a TableAdapter which has no code attached.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you. Stack Overflow isn't a service for code writing or finding resources for you. Did you even read the link I sent you? You need a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (which means we need to see your code).

Comment: There is literally no code to show you. I have no idea what you want. I am asking for a UI way to force the fields to rearrange.

Comment: "I have two TableAdapters in a project. Both are used to create a csv file that is sent to an application to create accounts." This code. And potentially the code that is loading the CSV.